# JS form validation not working

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, validation

I'm trying to validate some form fields using JS functions, but they don't seem to load or check the field when the submit button is clicked.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <?php require_once('logic.php'); ?>
    <h1>Add new Region/Entity</h1>
    <?php 
      if ($_POST['submitted']==1) {
        echo $error;
      }
    ?>
    <form action="logic.php" method="post" name="registration" onSubmit="return formValidation();">
      Region: <input type="text" name="region" value="<?php echo @$_POST['region']; ?>"><br>
      Description: <br><textarea name="description" cols="50" rows="10"><?php echo @$_POST['description']; ?></textarea><br>
      Remarks: <input type="text" name="remarks" value="<?php echo @$_POST['remarks']; ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="">
```

And here's the JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function formValidation() {
    var region = document.registration.region;
    var descr = document.registration.description;
    var remarks = document.registration.remarks;
    if(empty_validation()) {
      if(reg_validation()) {
        if(reg_letters()) {
          if (desc_letters()) {
            if (desc_validation()) {

            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
  function empty_validation() {
    var reg_len = region.value.length;
    var descr_len = descr.value.length;
    var rem_len = remarks.value.length;
    if (reg_len == 0 || decr_len == 0 || rem_len == 0) {
      alert("Please fill all the fields");
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
  function reg_validation() {
    if (reg_len > 50) {
      alert("Only 50 characters are allowed in the Region field");
      region.focus();
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
  function reg_letters() {
    var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    if(region.value.match(letters)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      alert('Region field must have only alphabetical characters');
      region.focus();
      return false;
    }
  }
  function desc_validation() {
    if (descr_len > 500) {
      alert("Only 500 characters are allowed in the description field");
      descr.focus();
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
  function desc_letters() {
    var iChars = "!@#$%^&*()+=-[]\\\';,./{}|\":<>?";
    for (var i = 0; i < descr_len; i++) {
      if (iChars.indexOf(descr.value.charAt(i)) != -1) {
        alert ("Your description has special characters. \nThese are not allowed.\n Please remove them and try again.");
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
</script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I'm posting values from the form to a PHP file. And I've used the `onSubmit` event in the form tag to initialize the `formValidation()` function. It isn't working for some reason.

Here's [a working example](http://appinventr.com/Task/interface.php) if you need one.

Comment: Have you tried debugging? There's an error in your validation - "region is not defined": `var reg_len = region.value.length;`

Comment: It isn't working! Doesn't help. What is expected? What is happening?

Comment: You can't declare Javascript variables in one function and then expect them to be available in every function. You have to declare them in every function in order to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to fix every little error you have, but the main problem is that variables aren't defined where you expect them to be. You can't declare a variable in one function and expect it to be available in the next (without passing it as a parameter or declaring it globally). For example, your `empty_validation` function should be this:

```
function empty_validation(region, descr, remarks) {
    var reg_len = region.value.length;  
    var descr_len = descr.value.length;  
    var rem_len = remarks.value.length;  

    if (reg_len == 0 || decr_len == 0 || rem_len == 0) {
        alert("Please fill all the fields");  
        return false;  
    }
    return true;  
}
```

And in your `formValidation` function, you call it like this:

```
if(empty_validation(region, descr, remarks)) {
```

This is just one example, and you would need to do it in a few places.

A few other things - you always return `false` from `formValidation`...did you mean to put `return true;` inside the innermost `if` statement? Also, since all you seem to be doing is calling each of those functions, you can probably put them into one big `if` statement, like this:

```
if (empty_validation() && reg_validation() && reg_letters() && desc_letters() && desc_validation()) {
    return true;
}
return false;
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped. http://appinventr.com/Task/interface.php

While the first validation works (somewhat, as the alert is displayed when a field is left blank), it doesn't seem to work after dismissing the alert. I have edited the code and included the variables like you suggested, it is live on that link

Comment: @AnimeshTripathi Are you able to debug this? For example, using Firebug or Developer Tools to watch what's happening in the browser's console? Anyways, the new error is "decr_len is not defined" here: `if (reg_len == 0 || decr_len == 0 || rem_len == 0)`. You seem to be mixing up variable names - between `decr_len` and `descr_len`

Comment: @AnimeshTripathi And for `desc_validation` function, you set the parameter as `deacr` but use it as `descr`

Comment: sorry for bothering you with typos, Ian. I finally figured something out, I'm able to validate most of the stuff by passing just the 3 variables I declared in the first function. I also tried seeing the errors using Chrome's Element Inspector but I'm not able to see them by typing 'console.log' or inspect(body).

Comment: @AnimeshTripathi No problem at all! Are you still getting errors? I minimally tested your site and it seems to validate correctly. So if you have Chrome's Developer Tools open, there's an "Elements" tab that I'm sure you have open, but you need to be looking at the "Console" tab. Have you been able to do that?

Comment: @AnimeshTripathi Well I'm sure it doesn't right now, I don't get any either because you seem to have fixed everything. Is everything working properly?

Comment: Yup, mostly everything is, as part of the task I also have to implement server-side validation via PHP, so fixing that atm. Thanks for the help!